# Is there a way to tie points in a mask to a subject that varies across moving frames?

Tags: masking

I am trying to create a mask over a moving subject in a video, and I would like to know if there is a method to modify the various points of it more precisely than moving them individually frame by frame. For example, if there is a command that at the very least works the same way as when you try to plot elements of a video that are then automatically recognized for the rest of the video.

Comment: do you mean tracking of VSE? did u try that?

Comment: No, I don't know how it works

Comment: here is a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=_1nxHEhf_ng but maybe you wanna search for "blender tracking tutorial" there are lots of them online